# How to enable anonymous access to part of the website in SiteMinder

Tags: siteminder

We are using SiteMinder secure-proxy for our website. The problem is that some parts of our website require anonymous authentication. For example ClickOnce installer and some WCF services. 
I was looking into `proxyrules.xml`, hoping that I can do sominthing in `nete:case`, but it seems not to be the case. I would be very thankful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Once again here's what I need:

- / - sso
- /test/ - sso
- /wcf/ - anonymous

How can I make `/wcf` exclusion?

** UPDATE **
I have found `IgnoreUrl` parameter of my WebAgent, but for some reason it is not applied and I'm still asked for username and password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was indeed the `IgnoreUrl` parameter I had to set. It wasn't working when I set it in the WebAgent configuration itself, but it did work when I set it via the `SiteMinder Administrative UI`.

**Update:** This reason for that is quite likely that the Agent Configuration object disallows local configurations of that kind via the `AllowLocalConfig` directive.

Comment: Similar problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266316/how-to-configure-a-public-rule-in-a-protected-realm-on-ca-siteminder