# How to configure a public rule in a protected realm on CA SiteMinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, siteminder

I want to configure SiteMinder to allow public access (for unauthenticated users) to a especific URI.

I have created a rule to allow access to a specific URI, and a Policy that applies to all users and that rule. The realm is protected by default. And when i try to access this URI SiteMinder block the access.

How can i configure the rule to allow public access for a especific URI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable anonymous access to part of the website in SiteMinder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859993/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-part-of-the-website-in-siteminder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a SiteMinder rule for this behavior.

Use the **IgnoreUrl** property on the web agent configuration object.